# How to create client id and secret for canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, oauth, clientid

I am trying to integrate canvas into my application. so I have tried to implement oauth2 
flow, i read this link https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.oauth.html

Performing the OAuth2 token request flow requires an application client ID and client secret. To obtain these application credentials, you will need to register your application. The client secret should never be shared.

For Canvas Cloud, you can request a client ID and secret from http://www.instructure.com/partners, or contact your account representative.

So I have tried to fill this form  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1C5vOpWHAAl-cltj2944-NM0w16AiCvKQFJae3euwwM8/viewform towards to get client Id and Secret.

once I filled and submitted the form I am getting this message

Your Request to Generate a Canvas Key for development has been submitted to instructor

So I don't where to go for getting client id and client secret after submitting the form.

I hope anyone help me to move forward in my work.

Comment: I think you need to ask Canvas for this. [link](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.developer_keys.html)  Who can grant or revoke scopes for a developer key?
For developer keys created in a specific root account, administrators for that account may grant or revoke scopes. When requesting a developer key, application owners should communicate with administrators which scopes their integrations require.

For global developer keys, an Instructure employee may grant or revoke scopes.